# in Poweryquery/pivot Merging two tables based on multiple column with unique values in both relative to other

Tags: merge, powerquery, outer-join, m

I have two tables: one for Sale and one for Target as shown below:

**Target** table:

| Date | mat | Tar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | A | 10 |
| 01/01/2020 | B | 12 |
| 01/01/2020 | C | 5 |
| 01/02/2020 | A | 10 |
| 01/02/2020 | B | 12 |
| 01/02/2020 | C | 5 |
| 01/03/2020 | A | 10 |
| 01/03/2020 | B | 12 |
| 01/03/2020 | C | 5 |

**Sale** table:

| Date | mat | S |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | A | 5 |
| 01/01/2020 | B | 6 |
| 01/01/2020 | C | 8 |
| 01/01/2020 | D | 1 |
| 01/02/2020 | A | 1 |
| 01/02/2020 | B | 2 |
| 01/02/2020 | D | 12 |
| 01/03/2020 | B | 1 |
| 01/03/2020 | C | 4 |
| 01/03/2020 | A | 5 |
| 01/03/2020 | F | 2 |

As you can see, there are certain material date combinations in the Target table that is not in the Sale table and vice versa.

I want to combine them in such a way that any missing material date combo not in Target will be added as a row with the new material and the sales will be added as a new column. Below is the ideal output:

| Date | mat | Tar | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | A | 10 | 5 |
| 01/01/2020 | B | 12 | 6 |
| 01/01/2020 | C | 5 | 8 |
| 01/02/2020 | A | 10 | 1 |
| 01/02/2020 | B | 12 | 2 |
| 01/02/2020 | C | 5 | 0 |
| 01/03/2020 | A | 10 | 5 |
| 01/03/2020 | B | 12 | 1 |
| 01/03/2020 | C | 5 | 4 |
| 01/01/2020 | D | 0 | 1 |
| 01/02/2020 | D | 0 | 12 |
| 01/03/2020 | F | 0 | 2 |

However, I am not getting this in PowerQuery when I choose a merge based on columns Date and mat when I choose a full outer-join to keep rows from both tables. My output is creating two date and material columns instead of one consolidated as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to append both tables together and group by the `Date` and `mat` columns to get all of the combinations of those two that you need and then join `Target` and `Sale` to that new table.

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Target, Sale}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Date", "mat"}, {}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"mat", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Sorted Rows", {"Date", "mat"}, Target, {"Date", "mat"}, "Target", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Target" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Target", {"Tar"}, {"Tar"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Target", {"Date", "mat"}, Sale, {"Date", "mat"}, "Sale", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Sale" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Sale", {"S"}, {"S"})
in
    #"Expanded Sale"
```

[image: Result Screenshot]

Replace null with 0 if desired.

---

**Edit:** I'm being overly complicated. You can take care `Tar` and `S` in the Group By by taking the max over those columns.

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Target, Sale}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Date", "mat"}, {{"Tar", each List.Max([Tar])}, {"S", each List.Max([S])}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```